# Why does my type's String() method not get called when printing a struct field?

Tags: go

I have a type called Password that is simply a string. I'd like to implement the Stringer interface by providing a String() method that redacts the value.

```
// Password a secret string that should not be leaked accidentally
type Password string

func (p Password) String() string {
    return "*********" // redact the password
}
```

This works as I would expect, if I attempt to print a Password.

```
p := Password("password not leaked here!")
fmt.Printf("password = %v \n", p) 
// got...  password = *********
```

But if the Password is a field within another struct, my String() method does not get called.

```
// User has a name and password
type User struct {
    name     string
    password Password
}

user := User{"Fran", Password("password was leaked!")}
fmt.Printf("user = %+v \n", user) 
// got...      user = {name:Fran password:password was leaked!}
// expected... user = {name:Fran password:*********}
```

Is there a way to make this call my String() method? It appears that the code actually calls `refect.Value.String()` instead.

https://play.golang.org/p/voBrSiOy-ol

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Password a secret string that should not be leaked accidentally
type Password string

func (p Password) String() string {
    return "*********" // redact the password
}

// User has a name and password
type User struct {
    name     string
    password Password
}

func main() {
    s := Password("password not leaked here!")
    fmt.Printf("password = %v \n", s) // password = ********* 

    user := User{"Fran", Password("password was leaked!")}
    fmt.Printf("user = %+v \n", user) // user = {name:Fran password:password was leaked!}
}
```

Comment: You cannot really protect secrets very well this way. Better to encrypt it at rest. You want to prevent casual dumps in log files and such so don't go crazy. A programmer with debugger tools would defeat anything you used if they focused on it.

Comment: "Why doesn't ..." is answerd most of the time by careful reading of the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from the package fmt documentation:

> When printing a struct, fmt cannot and therefore does not invoke formatting methods such as Error or String on unexported fields.

The field `password` is not exported, so it is not inspected to figure out it implements Stringer. Export it, and it will work:

```
type User struct {
    name     string
    Password Password
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "failsafe" to protect yourself against accidental default formatting, you can hide your password values behind pointers by boxing a `*string` in your Password type.

https://play.golang.org/p/vE-cEXHp2ii

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Password a secret string that should not be leaked accidentally
type Password struct{
 *string
}
func (p Password) String() string {
    return "*********" // redact the password
}

func NewPassword(pword string) Password {
    s := new(string)
    *s = pword
    return Password{s}
}

// User has a name and password
type User struct {
    name     string
    password Password
}

func main() {
    user := User{"Fran", NewPassword("this password is safe from default formatting")}
    fmt.Printf("user = %+v \n", user)
}
```

Output:

```
user = {name:Fran password:{string:0xc00008a040}}
```